# Jquery/Javascript Exibir um dentre dois itens aleatoriamente a cada acesso

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia amigos! Tudo bem?

Meu caso é o seguinte: Tenho dois números de celulares, e quero que a cada acesso, eu exiba um numero diferente.
Eu tentei fazer algo com Math.random entre 2 e 1, com um desvio condicional de se for 1 eu exibo o numero um e se for 2 eu exibo o numero dois Segue o modelo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                if( x == 1) {
                    $('#number').text('numero um');
                } else {
                    $('#number').text('numero dois');
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="number"></p>
```

Na minha cabeça seria 50% para cada número, porém descobri que aleatoriamente ele pode repetir o número.

Minha dúvida é: existe alguma forma de trabalhar com um número diferente para cada acesso sem repetir (client side) ou devo buscar por alguma solução do lado do servidor?

Pensando em client side ainda, eu estava pensando em fazer algo com cookie para tentar exibir cada número sem repetir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua ideia é que a mesma pessoa veja aleatoriamente, a solução que me vem a cabeça é o cookie ou local storage, assim você guarda chave com o numero 1 no primeiro acesso e coloca uma logica

```js
var num = 1;//'O VALOR DO SEU COOKIE OU LOCAL STORAGE';
if(num == 1){
  console.log('exibe numero dois');
}else{
  console.log('exibe numero um');
  //altera o valor do cookie/ local storage aqui   
}
```